# Why is the success event for Dropzone.js returning invalid and inaccurate JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm only having this problem on the remote server. It works fine locally, and was working fine remotely as well until today. I can't find anything that's changed other than the addition of the `accept` event (see below). I tried removing that, and I still have the same problem. I'm on Dropzone 4.0.1. I tried updating to 4.2.0, but there was no change in behavior.

Anyway, when I upload a file with Dropzone and log the `response` to the console, I get this invalid JSON:

```
{"success":200,"filename":"\/__print\/medium-article-test.pdf"}{"success":200,"filename":"\/__print\/medium-article-test-20151012163000.pdf"}
```

I checked the server, and only the first file actually uploaded. It seems like it's triggering an upload twice, and firing a single success event for two separate upload triggers.

I believe this is the only relevant code:

```
// Prevent Dropzone from attaching twice.
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var dropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone', {
  accept:         accept,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  autoDiscover:   false,
  fallback:       fallback,
  maxFiles:       1,
  url:            '/TRIGGER/pawprint/upload_file',
});

dropzone.on('success', function(file, response) {
  console.log(response);
  document.querySelector('input[type=hidden][name=file]').value = JSON.parse(response).filename;
  buttonSubmit.disabled = false;
});
```

…but just in case, here's the full file:

```
// Disable the submission. We'll re-enable it after the file uploads.
var buttonSubmit = document.querySelector('button[type=submit]');
buttonSubmit.disabled = true;

/**
 * Fallback to a plain form if there's an issue using Dropzone.js.
 * @author Curtis Blackwell
 * @return {void}
 */
var fallback = function() {
  document.querySelector('#dropzone').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#dropzone-fallback').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('input[type=file][name=file]').setAttribute('required', true);
  buttonSubmit.disabled = false;
}


/**
 * List of all acceptable file types.
 * @type {Array}
 */
var unacceptableFileTypes = [
  // A `.pages`' file.type is a blank string.
  '',
  'application/zip'
]

/**
 * Filter out files that we can't print.
 * @author Curtis Blackwell
 * @param  {object}   file File data.
 * @param  {Function} done Function to call once done (see Dropzone docs).
 * @return {void}
 */
var accept = function(file, done) {
  if (unacceptableFileTypes.indexOf(file.type) !== -1) {
    done("Sorry, but we can't print a file of that type.");
  } else {
    done();
  }
}

// Prevent Dropzone from attaching twice.
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var dropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone', {
  accept:         accept,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  autoDiscover:   false,
  fallback:       fallback,
  maxFiles:       1,
  url:            '/TRIGGER/pawprint/upload_file',
});

dropzone.on('success', function(file, response) {
  console.log(response);
  document.querySelector('input[type=hidden][name=file]').value = JSON.parse(response).filename;
  buttonSubmit.disabled = false;
});

dropzone.on('removedfile', function(file) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '/TRIGGER/pawprint/delete_file',
    data: {
      file: document.querySelector('input[type=hidden][name=file]').value
    }
  });

  buttonSubmit.disabled = true;
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

*I'm sharing what I can of the server-side code as suggested in the comments.*

The static methods are a part of a licensed CMS, so I can't share that code, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue. I use those methods pretty frequently and never run into problems there. However, `File::upload()` adds a timestamp to uploaded files if the filename is already taken, which is why you see that timestamp above.

Also, I just tried doing nothing but `echo json_encode($_FILES);` in the upload method and got this back (only not prettified of course):

```
{
  "file": {
    "name": "medium-article-test.pdf",
    "type": "application/pdf",
    "tmp_name": "/tmp/php6CBpCW",
    "size": 459045,
    "size_human_readable": "448.29 KB",
    "error": 0,
    "error_message": "",
    "success": true
  }
}
{
  "file": {
    "name": "medium-article-test.pdf",
    "type": "application/pdf",
    "tmp_name": "/tmp/php6CBpCW",
    "size": 459045,
    "size_human_readable": "448.29 KB",
    "error": 0,
    "error_message": "",
    "success": true
  }
}
```

Anyway, here's the server-side code I *can* share, though I'm pretty sure this isn't where the problem lies:

```
<?php

class Hooks_pawprint extends Hooks
{
    /**
     * Upload a file.
     * @author Curtis Blackwell
     * @return string Path to file.
     */
    public function pawprint__upload_file()
    {
        $file = $_FILES[key($_FILES)];

        if ($filename = $this->addon->api('pawprint')->uploadFile($file)) {
            $return = array(
                'success'  => 200,
                'filename' => $filename
            );
        } else {
            $return = array(
                'error' => 400
            );
        }

        echo json_encode($return);
    }
}


class API_pawprint extends API
{
    /**
     * Upload a file.
     * @author Curtis Blackwell
     * @param  array  $file The file array.
     * @return string       The path to the uploaded file.
     */
    public function uploadFile($file)
    {
        // Slugify filenames to prevent errors.
        $file['name'] = Slug::make($file['name'], array(
            'maintain_case' => true,
            'custom_replacements' => array(
                '#' => ' hash ',
                '?' => ' question mark ',
                '/' => ' slash '
            )
        ));

        return File::upload($file, '__print');
    }
}
```

Comment: From the JSON output alone (as you haven't shown your server code), it looks like your server side script is doing a loop and outputting JSON through each iteration instead of going through the loop first and then doing the JSON output

Comment: There's no loop. I limited Dropzone to a single file and I just grab the first file in the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: Well somewhere you are outputting JSON twice, so show your server side code as that is what is creating the JSON response

Comment: @PatrickEvans Even the `$_FILES` array is wonky, so I kinda doubt it's the code itself, but I shared what I can.